# How to prevent direct viewing of html files using htaccess?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, security

I would like to prevent users to view the contents of all html files.

Example:
website.com/join/view_template.html (and it will display all the codes including the smarty)

I would like them to be redirected to 404 page if they do this.

I'm not sure if this is possible in htaccess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following line in htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/.+\.html
```

This will return 404 not found error for all .html files.

Comment: Wow it works! Thanks! Are there any security measures needed aside from this?

Comment: Also can I use this for .css and .js `RedirectMatch 404 ^/.+\.css RedirectMatch 404 ^/.+\.js`

Comment: Amy , this is a mod-alias based solution. Its safe and faster in performance. Yes ,you can include your css and other extensions to. To include multiple extens ,you can use the following pattern **^/.+\.(html|css|other)**

Comment: Awesome thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this although I didn't try it for now,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.html - [R=404]
```

Comment: I tried but the content in the html is still displaying...